# Adding taghelper directive in Blazor razor file returns error

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

As i'm currently evaluating Blazor in VisualStudio 2019, i get next error when adding a taghelper to a razor (view) file:

The tag helper:

```
@addTagHelper *, BlazorPOC.Validations
```

The generated error:

[image]

Any clue ?

Kind regards,
Emmanuel Nuyttens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically just follow what the generated error says.

Create a `@using` statement at the top of your file:

```
@using BlazorPOC.Validations
```